# Multi-dimensional Gauss integral with complex non-symmetric coefficients

Tags: matrices, definite-integrals, complex-integration

Is there a closed formula that evaluates the integral,
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_1 .. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx_D
  \exp\left(-\sum_{\mu=1}^D \sum_{\nu=1}^D a_{\mu\nu} x_{\mu} x_{\nu} \right),
$$
where $a_{\mu\nu} \in \mathbb{C}$ ($\mu=1,\dots,D$, $\nu=1,\dots,D$) do not constitute a Hermitian or complex-symmetric matrix?

**Edit** (2015-9-9):

I realized that the quadratic form in the exponent can always be expressed with a complex symmetric matrix, $a'_{\mu\nu} := (a_{\mu\nu}+a_{\nu\mu})/2$.
That is,
$$
\sum_{\mu=1}^D \sum_{\nu=1}^D a_{\mu\nu} x_{\mu} x_{\nu}
= \sum_{\mu=1}^D \sum_{\nu=1}^D a'_{\mu\nu} x_{\mu} x_{\nu}.
$$
I also realized that I do not know a formula for $I$ even in the case where $a_{\mu\nu}$ is complex symmetric. Therefore, I would like to change my question to the following:
**Is  there a closed formula that evaluates the integral $I$ above if $a_{\mu\nu}$ constitute a complex symmetric matrix?**

Comment: if i remember correctly, you may analytically continue the result for symmetric matrices to the general case. The reason is related to the fact that the symmetric matrices form a dense subset of $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and the function $e^{-\vec{x}^ta\vec
{x}}$ is entire in the whole parameter space. but at the moment i can't figure out the details...

Comment: @tired Thanks for the hint.

Comment: In "Keldysh technique and non-linear $\sigma$-models:basic principles and applications" by Kamenev&Levchenko is stated:
"Finally one notes that the right hand side is an analytic function in $\Re{a_{ij}}$ and$Im{a_{ij}}$. Therefore on may analytically continue it to reach an arbritrary complex matrix $a_{ij}$....as long as the integral is well defined...
That's the best i have found so far